# How to delete server certificate pointed to by load balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm trying to upgrade some certificates on my terraform-managed infrastructure. The tf plan is to delete an aws_elb.load_balancer that is using the old aws_iam_server_certificate, and then create a new aws_iam_server_certificate, and point a new listener at it. But when the plan is applied, the listener is never deleted, so the old cert cannot be deleted.

I know the listener is not deleted because when I run terraform plan again I see that the old listener still needs to be destroyed.

How can I convince terraform to destroy this listener and the old cert, and create the new cert and listener, all by doing a simple `terraform apply`, that is, without manually calling `terraform destroy?`

## plan

```
~ module.ecs.aws_ecs_service.service
    task_definition: "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:12345:task-definition/dle-glossary-api-sandbox:20" => "${aws_ecs_task_definition.task_definition.arn}"

-/+ module.ecs.aws_ecs_task_definition.admin_task_definition
    arn:                   "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:12345:task-definition/dle-glossary-api-sandbox-admin:20" => "<computed>"
    container_definitions: "93b15fbec63f6cae8389cc6befa505890002ec4f" => "abf62f02c60dbfa30952def0eb69fec96b455205" (forces new resource)
    family:                "dle-glossary-api-sandbox-admin" => "dle-glossary-api-sandbox-admin"
    network_mode:          "" => "<computed>"
    revision:              "20" => "<computed>"

-/+ module.ecs.aws_ecs_task_definition.task_definition
    arn:                   "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:12345:task-definition/dle-glossary-api-sandbox:20" => "<computed>"
    container_definitions: "9e38e676174426b7c8179446f788d7eeffa90583" => "92fd7350f9798461d78f80bfca4fccea6cea68db" (forces new resource)
    family:                "dle-glossary-api-sandbox" => "dle-glossary-api-sandbox"
    network_mode:          "" => "<computed>"
    revision:              "20" => "<computed>"

~ module.ecs.aws_elb.load_balancer
needs to delete listener 2240553862, create a listener. This should free up the cert resource. Why can't we delete it?

listener.2240553862.instance_port:       "80" => "0"
    listener.2240553862.instance_protocol:   "http" => ""
    listener.2240553862.lb_port:             "443" => "0"
    listener.2240553862.lb_protocol:         "https" => ""
    listener.2240553862.ssl_certificate_id:  "arn:aws:iam::12345:server-certificate/dle-glossary-api-cert-sandbox009476f6b7..." => ""
listener.3057123346.instance_port:       "80" => "80"
    listener.3057123346.instance_protocol:   "http" => "http"
    listener.3057123346.lb_port:             "80" => "80"
    listener.3057123346.lb_protocol:         "http" => "http"
    listener.3057123346.ssl_certificate_id:  "" => ""
listener.~1222724879.instance_port:      "" => "80"
    listener.~1222724879.instance_protocol:  "" => "http"
    listener.~1222724879.lb_port:            "" => "443"
    listener.~1222724879.lb_protocol:        "" => "https"
    listener.~1222724879.ssl_certificate_id: "" => "${var.ssl_certificate_arn}"

-/+ module.iam.aws_iam_server_certificate.cert
    arn:               "arn:aws:iam::12345:server-certificate/dle-glossary-api-cert-sandbox009476f6b7..." => "<computed>"
    certificate_body:  "x" => "y" (forces new resource)
    certificate_chain: "z" => "q"
    name:              "dle-glossary-api-cert-sandbox009476f6b7..." => "<computed>"
    name_prefix:       "dle-glossary-api-cert-sandbox" => "dle-glossary-api-cert-sandbox"
    path:              "/" => "/"
    private_key:       "xyz" => "zxy" (forces new resource)
```

The error is:

```
 aws_iam_server_certificate.cert (deposed #0): DeleteConflict:
    Certificate: ASCAI25L32IRFVVIZQNIQ is currently in use by
    arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:12345:loadbalancer/dle-glossary-api-sandbox. Please
    remove it first before deleting it from IAM.  status code: 409,
```

Comment: How does the configuration look? (don't share secrets :D ) Are you using interpolation to link the cert?

Comment: Why are you creating new listener? Just change config for existing listener